# How do i remove the padding/margin of my html file?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I tried to make my picture go to the edge, i tryed setting margin/padding to 0 in classes, but I kept having this little leftover margin:

[image: picture of the wired margin]

I read that I should manually reset margin and padding because some browsers come with a default padding if none is specified but it hasn't worked.
Right now my CSS code looks like this:

```
.navpicture {
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  background-color: white;

}
```

Comment: Can you share more of your HTML and CSS? it's not clear what's causing the issue from what you've provided so far in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "reset" (i.e. set to 0) the margin of the `body` element, not that of your own div. So you should add this rule to your CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```